# JavaScript compare function not being called?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an object which contains an array. I am trying to sort the array by a win rate, but the following code doesn't seem to do anything at all. I can't see that the compareWinRate function is even getting called, but I am not sure why not.

```
let statistics = {
  wins: 0,
  kills: 0,
  deaths: 0,
  assists: 0,
  heroes: [],
};

statistics.heroes[hero1] = { matches: 5, wins: 2 };
statistics.heroes[hero2] = { matches: 5, wins: 4 };

function compareWinRate(a, b) {
  return ((b.wins / b.matches) - (a.wins / a.matches));
}

statistics.heroes.sort(compareWinRate);
```

If I display the array before and after the sort statement, they are the same.

Comment: `.sort` (and other array methods) only works with numeric array properties (`array[0], array[1]` etc) and completely ignores named ones. So, from the `.sort`'s standpoint, your array is empty.

Comment: What are `hero1` and `hero2`? How do you display the array? Please provide the full code.

Comment: When you say `statistics.heroes["hero1"] = { matches: 5, wins: 2 };` you are not filling up the array, you are just adding property to heroes object & keeping heroes array empty & that's why the compare function didn't get called. So you can try below solution given by Gilad

Comment: I think @georg may have hit on the problem, as it does not appear that the compare function is even being called. The keys (`hero1`, `hero2`, etc.) are indeed strings.

Answer (score 2):

`compareWinRate` seems fine to me.

Just assign the stats objects to numeric indexes in the array:

```
statistics.heroes[0] = { matches: 5, wins: 2 };
statistics.heroes[1] = { matches: 5, wins: 4 };
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. After loading the first array as in my original post, I then went ahead and created a new array of stats objects with numeric indices which allowed me to sort them properly for display.